# Gitlab CI /var/run/docker.sock: write: broken pipe

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

Trying to set up a runner and coming up with this issue:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.10.4 (b32125f)
Using Docker executor with image php:5.6 ...
ERROR: Failed to create container volume for /builds/ppw write unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: write: broken pipe
ERROR: Preparation failed: write unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: write: broken pipe
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image php:5.6 ...
ERROR: Failed to create container volume for /builds/ppw write unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: write: broken pipe
ERROR: Preparation failed: write unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: write: broken pipe
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using Docker executor with image php:5.6 ...
ERROR: Failed to create container volume for /builds/ppw write unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: write: broken pipe
ERROR: Preparation failed: write unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: write: broken pipe
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Build failed (system failure): write unix @->/var/run/docker.sock: write: broken pipe
```

I've tried downgrading the `gitlab-ci-multi-runner` but I still have the same issue - `broken pipe`.

System is running: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

#### My .gitlab-ci.yml

```
before_script:
# Install dependencies
- bash ci/docker_install.sh > /dev/null
# We test PHP5.6
test:5.6:
  image: php:5.6
  script:
  - phpunit --configuration phpunit_myapp.xml
# We test PHP7.0
test:7.0:
  image: php:7.0
  script:
  - phpunit --configuration phpunit_myapp.xml
```

#### My ci/docker_install.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
# We need to install dependencies only for Docker
[[ ! -e /.dockerenv ]] && exit 0
set -xe
# Install git (the php image doesn't have it) which is required by composer
apt-get update -yqq
apt-get install git -yqq
# Install phpunit, the tool that we will use for testing
curl --location --output /usr/local/bin/phpunit https://phar.phpunit.de/phpunit.phar
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/phpunit
```

Any help would be appreciated, I have tried reading up here: [GitlabCI build failed, docker.sock: write: broken pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40126748/gitlabci-build-failed-docker-sock-write-broken-pipe)

When i do `docker ps` I don't have any containers listed.

```
$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
```

Comment: Does this work now ? Gitlab had to temporary shutdown for a few hours because of a database issue. See https://about.gitlab.com/2017/02/01/gitlab-dot-com-database-incident/

Comment: I've still got the same issue this morning :/